# Visa, MasterCard or any other network copy Bitcoin blockchain tech?

Tags: private-blockchains, visa

I read an article (below) that explained how complicated the payment industry is and thus is why it is relatively expensive.

Could a network like Visa eventually copy Bitcoin, and thus cut everyone else out?

Would this potentially end Bitcoin?

This is the article: [THE PAYMENTS INDUSTRY EXPLAINED: The Trends Creating New Winners And Losers In The Card-Processing Ecosystem](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-payments-industry-explained-2014-12?&platform=bi-androidapp)

Answer (score 5):

It would make no sense for Visa to copy Bitcoin.
Visa is a company built around control of a payment network. Visa's system only works because they control access and payment verification, which is what makes them money.
In Bitcoin, no single entity is in sole control. There is no way to make money off of the transactions on the network except to put in the validation work and reap the mining reward. By copying Bitcoin they'd destroy their own business strategies.

What they could do is to bastardize the Bitcoin system into a centrally controlled "Private Blockchain". However, if you're not trying to achieve decentralized control, there is little other incentive to use a blockchain in the first place. They could create a much more efficient system with themselves in control, as blockchains are inherently inefficient – it's the price for being decentralized.